# spring tries to parse @Value key in junittest

Tags: java, spring, junit, properties

I have a class with an @Value Annotation

```
public class ServiceImpl {
    @Value("${timeout}")
    private long timeout;
    ...
}
```

And an Unittest

```
@UnitTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test/service-test-spring.xml")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test/service-test.properties")
public class ServiceTest {
    ...
}
```

with the context

```
<bean id="service" class="ServiceImpl"/>
```

When I run the test, the context cannot be created due to following exception:

```
Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [long]; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${timeout}"
```

Somehow it wants to parse the key instead of the property from the propertiesfile:

```
timeout=18000
```

Suggestions on how to fix this are appreciated.

Comment: are you  sure that your timeout in your property file is a long and not a double / String? Maybe you can show your property-file as well?

Comment: I edited it, its the same key value as in the application.